# error while installing controller and agent on k8s: "CRD must be installed"

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubectl, master-slave

> resource mapping not found for name: "jenkins-master" namespace:
> "jenkins" from "role.yaml": no matches for kind "RoleBinding" in
> version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" ensure CRDs are installed
> first

i tried to install agnos but it didnt help.

Comment: The error message is misleading. It looks like you are just referencing a role binding that doesn't exist. Can you show your role.yaml?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" to "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1". I was getting error for a different setup and changing the version worked for me.